# Pandas datetime64 turns into Timestamp on access and cannot be re-inserted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I get a `FutureWarning` from the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,1,1,tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)]})
df.loc[:, "b"] = pd.NaT   # create new columns
df.info()
df.loc[0, "b"] = df.loc[0, "a"]
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype              
---  ------  --------------  -----              
 0   a       1 non-null      datetime64[ns, UTC]
 1   b       0 non-null      datetime64[ns]     
dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](1), datetime64[ns](1)
```

> FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise in a future error of pandas. Value '2023-01-01 01:01:00+00:00' has dtype incompatible with datetime64[ns], please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.

## How do I avoid it?

constraints:

1. the `create new columns` line adds *many* columns (I have a list of columns instead of just `"b"` in the actual code), and *many* rows.
2. The data is filled in one row at a time, with TZ-aware data.

So, basically, I have to add many columns of `dtype=datetime64[ns, UTC]` in some simple way.

Is there a better way than

```
df["b"] = df.b.dt.tz_localize(datetime.timezone.utc)
```

repeated over all time columns?

Answer (score -1):

You can insert a Series of aware datetime directly:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [
            pd.Timestamp(2023, 1, 1, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
            pd.Timestamp(2023, 1, 1, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
        ]
    }
)
df.loc[:, "b"] = pd.to_datetime([None] * df.loc[:, "a"].size, utc=True)
df.loc[0, "b"] = df.loc[0, "a"]
```

```
df
                          a                         b
0 2023-01-01 01:01:00+00:00 2023-01-01 01:01:00+00:00
1 2023-01-01 01:01:00+00:00                       NaT

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype              
---  ------  --------------  -----              
 0   a       2 non-null      datetime64[ns, UTC]
 1   b       1 non-null      datetime64[ns, UTC]
dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](2)
memory usage: 164.0 bytes
```

You gain some efficiency by using pandas built-in datetime exclusively, since this avoids conversion steps. In the specific case, creating the aware datetime series *will* cost more compute than just setting `pd.NaT`, but save the localization step later on - which might cost even more compute.

Comment: looks like I have another "dv" fan :)